# Searching across a few fields in Django. Not sure how to chain them

Tags: django, search

I have a few fields I'd like users to be searching across when looking for Restaurants on my site; `cuisine_style` (m2m), `neighborhoods` (m2m) and `event_space` (m2m).

These are presented to the user as dropdown boxes. In addition I'd also like to supply a text field where the user can type in anything and have it search against the restaurants `name` (CharField) and `keywords` (CharField).

I can write a view to display the results of ONE of these filters applied, but not all of them. Oh, and each dropdown would obviously have a null/empty default.

Any ideas? Here's what I got to start with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
if request.GET.get('q'):
    search_terms = request.GET.get('q')
    restaurant_list = Restaurant.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=search_terms) |
        Q(keywords__icontains=search_terms) |
    ).order_by('-user__date_joined')
```

but that only covers one field. what about all the dropdowns?

Oh(!) I guess i could compile ALL the GET parameters and split them up and dump them into a list, but not all values are single words.

I am also open to Haystack but I have no idea.

Comment: Does "all of them" mean "and"?  Cuisine style AND neighborhood AND event space?  If it means "and", that's automatic.  If it means OR you have to do some work.  What specific logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: I suggest to you to move to POST method. You are talking about dropdown list. This may be a lot of characters.

Comment: My logic is Cuisine style AND Neighborhood AND Event Space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With post and field model form you can prepare a list of Q (named qs in sample) with posteds values:

```
from django.db.models import Q
if request.method == 'POST':

    qs = []
    if form.is_valid():
       cuisine_styles = form.cleaned_data['cuisine_style']
       neighborhoods  = form.cleaned_data['neighborhoods']
       search_terms = form.cleaned_data['search_terms']

       if cuisine_styles: qs.append( Q( cuisine_style__in = cuisine_styles ) )
       if neighborhoods: qs.append( Q(neighborhoods__in = neighborhoods ) )
       for s in search_terms.split(' '):
           qs.append(  Q( name__icontains=s) )
           qs.append(  Q( keywords__icontains=s) )

       f = None
       for q in qs:
           if f is None: f = q
           else: f |=q

        restaurant_list = Restaurant.objects.filter( f ).order_by('-user__date_joined')
        #show results ....
else:
    #show form ....
```

I assume that your dropdown boxes are [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: Hrm, Im not using a formset. I simply pass a dict for each field and then loop through them in the template to build the dropdowns. Perhaps this is where I should consider redesigning. My current 'dropdowns' are single selects, not multiple. Although there is likely power to select multiples, most of the time, with this data set, it will be considered over-engineered. Any ideas on my more generic implementation?

Comment: |=q? not sure i get that part.

Comment: f |= q means f = f | q. Only to make a big OR with all conditions. You can refine query to make an OR with name and keywords and make an AND with other fields.